# SwiftUI - Keyboard pushes everything up

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard

Faced up a problem, where the keyboard pushes everything up. Here is an example:

```
var body: some Scene {
  WindowGroup {
    
    let full = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
      
      // View 1
      
      Color.blue
        .frame(height: full / 4)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        .zIndex(1)
      
      ZStack {
        
        // View 2
        
        Color.green
          .frame(height: full / 2)
          .padding(.bottom, full / 2)
        
        // View 3
        
        ZStack {
          Color.red
          TextField("Placeholder", text: .constant(""))
        }
        .frame(height: full / 2)
        .padding(.top, full / 2)
      }
      .frame(height: full)
      .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
    .frame(height: full)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
  }
}
```

[image]

How to ignore view 1 (blue) or view 2 (green) from pushing up?
Or make all views respect their place?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is solving your issue but might be worth a try

```
WindowGroup {
          VStack(spacing: 0) {
              Color.blue.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 4)
              Color.green.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 4)
              ZStack {
                  Color.red
                  TextField("Placeholder", text: .constant(""))
              }
          }
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, this works. Unfortunately, I must use a more complex layout with ZStack's. And looks like issues exactly with ZStack's